# git http backend problems push data compiler

Tags: git, git-server

how to make push code compiler using git http backend

If the user pushes now, the code compiler that was pushed should return the result

TODO: get commit message and push data code compiler :_

I tried to write

```
import { Git } from 'node-git-server';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { join, dirname } from 'path';
import { existsSync, mkdirSync } from 'fs';
import http from 'http';

// Use import.meta.url to get the current module's URL
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
// Use dirname to get the directory name
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

const port = 2222;

const repoPath = join(__dirname, './repo');
const startFolder = join(__dirname, './compiler');

// Check if the repo folder exists, and create it if not
if (!existsSync(repoPath)) {
  mkdirSync(repoPath);
}
const repos = new Git(repoPath, {
  autoCreate: true,
  checkout: true,
});

repos.on('push',  (push) => {

  push.log(`push ${push.repo}/${push.commit} ( ${push.branch} )`);

  // **TODO: get commit message and push data code compiler :_**
  
  push.log();
  push.accept()
});


repos.server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  repos.handle(req, res);
});

repos.server.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(`node-git-server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```